# PHP Simple HTML DOM Incomplete echo's

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

So, I am trying to echo a page in PHP Simple HTML DOM for a project I am working on and it seems that it is skipping most of the page. I have spent around 6 hours on this and am stuck so I am asking for help.

Can't get much more simple then this

```
    <?php 
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    include('simple_html_dom.php');                                             //includes simpledomhtml
    echo file_get_html('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198049810642/games?tab=all')->plaintext; 
?>
```

Yet the output is completely missing ALL of the text in the middle including Game names, hours, links and so on in the middle. I assume this is a result of that part of the page being within a  section, but I thought PHP Simple HTML DOM was capable of parsing through things like this. Try it you're self, it makes no sense. I have tried countless variants of code. Please help.

---

So I think you are right about the plaintext output so instead of moving this post in a direction I don't need I am making a new topic with a more focused question
[PHP Simple HTML DOM Outputting Blank Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109213/php-simple-html-dom-outputting-blank-page)

Comment: Can you paste the output somewhere? (pastebin.com for example). :)

Comment: Well processing the file with ->plaintext should remove all html tags... That can probably cause the results you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `->plaintext` method you won't be able to fetch contents that is generated dynamically with javascript, as it looks to be on the page you are loading.

With only

```
file_get_html('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198049810642/games?tab=all');
```

You should see a duplicate of the page?

Then just start processing the items you want to keep.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: I feel that this is indeed the case so I have stopped with this experiment which seems to just be a waste of time and moved on to posting my original question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109213/php-simple-html-dom-outputting-blank-page