# PHP Simple HTML DOM Outputting Blank Page

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

So, I am attempting to output the playtimes of a person playing L4D2 (game ID 550) and while this script used to work, it now only outputs a blank page using this "PHP Simple HTML DOM" I had backed up here http://rghost.net/45405596. If I download and try to use the newest simple dom from their website instead of showing nothing it shows

> Call to undefined function file_get_dom() on line 9"

Here is the code I am running

```
    <?php
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $lines = file('profile2.txt');                                                       //reads in the file with the list of user numbers
    foreach ($lines as $usernumber) {                                                  //loops line by line
    $link = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<sitenumber>/games?tab=all";   //link format
    $link = preg_replace('/(<sitenumber>)/i',$usernumber,$link);               //puts usernumber into link format
    $link = preg_replace('/\s*/m','',$link);                                   //remove the stupid space
    $html = file_get_dom($link);                                               //calls the dom function
    $divline = $html->find('div[id=game_550] h5', 0);                          //finds the div block and then the h5 line
    $divline = preg_replace('/(<(\/)?h5>)/i', '', $divline);                   //replaces the <h5> tag with nothing
    if ($divline != '') {
        list($hrs,$u1,$u2,$u4) = explode(" ",$divline);
        if (($hrs < 90) && ($hrs > 1)) {
            echo $hrs." - ".$link."<br>";                                  //prints results
        }
    }
    $html->__destruct();
    unset($html); 
while(@ob_end_clean()); 


}
?>
```

This points to a text file named profile3.txt which contains this number "76561198049810642"

Any suggestions as to why this is outputting nothing? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [Steam Web API](http://steamcommunity.com/dev)?

Comment: Two reasons. The first one is I have no idea how to use it and I know how to use Simple Dom (at least I thought I did). Second off when I DID try to use the API the only page I could get to work which was http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&appids=440&steamid=76561198049810642 it output this in plaintext without any sort of formatting http://pastebin.com/NegPtvcJ and I have no idea how to sort that mess into just showing the Playtimeforever for game 550

Comment: That's not "plaintext"; that's [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).  There's a PHP function called [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) that will allow you to parse that output with ease.

Comment: hmm, guess I don't know much when it comes to json. Is there a way I could get a simple example of how to use json_decode() to do what I am trying to do above? In short I am trying to output the Playtimeforever for an appid of 550, if you need I could email my steamkey. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some (untested) code that should help you get started using the [Steam Web API](http://steamcommunity.com/dev):

```
$api_key = '...';
$steam_id = '...';
$game_id = 550;

$json = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=' . $api_key . '&steamid=' . $steam_id . '&format=json');

$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data->response->games as $game) { 
    if ($game->appid == $game_id) {
        echo 'Playtime for ', $game_id, ' is ' . $game->playtime_forever;
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing xD People here are so much smarter then me lol. I will give this a shot and post the finished code incase anyone else like me needs help. As long as I can figure it out

Comment: `$something` is called a [variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php).  You can store the playtime in hours in a variable using `$playtime = $game->playtime_forever / 60;`;

Comment: So, question. http://pastebin.com/ReXGyY4h. Made some small tweaks to your code, it worked like a charm by the way. My current question is, Is there a way to implement the last bit of code where it only shows things under a certain hour amount. In this case it would be under a certain minute amount since the API outputs in minutes. I can't figure out how it declares playtime_forever so I am unable to do logic on it. (reposed question to people know what I was talking about, previous link had my steam key xD)

Comment: @SuperMar1o:  Not a problem.  Remember to mark the question as correct by clicking the green check-mark by my answer.

Comment: I have another question regarding the filtering results, should I make another question with this since it is somewhat different? Also, where should I put the $playtime = xxx line at in the file? Anywhere I put it causes errors.

Comment: @SuperMar1o:  You would put `$playtime = ...` inside of the `if` statement inside the 2nd `foreach` loop.  And yes, feel free to post another question.

Comment: hahaha, I feel so smart. I figured it out xD


  if (($playtime < 64480) && ($playtime > 1)) {
        echo 'Playtime for ', $usernumber, ' is ' . $playtime."<br>";

Thanks a bunch!